# engaged_session_event and session_engaged parameters in GA4 Raw Data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to figure out exactly how engaged sessions are calculated in Google Analytics 4. So far I can clearly see that when the event is logged with the `session_engaged` parameter equal to 1, the session is considered engaged.

[image]

However, all of our conversion events are sent via Measurement Protocol, and while the definition of the engaged session states the following: "An engaged session is a session that lasts longer than 10 seconds, has a conversion event, or has at least 2 pageviews or screenviews.", I am not sure the conversion events sent via Measurement Protocol are taken into account.

I can see that the conversion events sent via MP don't have the "session_engaged" event parameter when studying the raw data, but instead there is another one, called `engaged_session_event`.

[image]

So I'm a little bit confused about this and would love to have some clarification as to whether the second parameter makes the session an "engaged one" or not.

Answer (score 0):

Good question,
`session_engaged` is the metric that is commonly used to calculate engagement, an `engaged_session_event` Includes the number of sessions the user is engaged in.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/personalization/bigquery

I suspect, but do not know, that it is an engaged event is triggered inside GA4 with the relevant data not being exported in the raw data so unfortunately no amount of digging will provide the answer. I think this because I can adjust the time element of engagement in my configurations but nothing in the export changes (except the count of engaged sessions)